# VBA find and replace with formulas (trouble getting rows to update)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a `find` and `replace`, where the replacement is a formula. I can't figure out how to get the formula to reference the row # of the cell it's replacing. Can somebody help me understand how this works?

The value for find is

> NEED DATE FOR PUBLISHING UNKNOWN

and the replacement value would be

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'VideoIndex.xlsx'!YouTube_ALLDATA,2,FALSE)
```

with `A1` being the value that changes each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that using Excel Formula as far as I know. But it is possible using VBA.

This code will do this for you. Which is a sample on this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

```
Sub rep()

Dim c As Range
Dim firstaddress As Range

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find("NEED DATE FOR PUBLISHING UNKNOWN", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = "=VLOOKUP(A" & c.Row & ",'VideoIndex.xlsx'!YouTube_ALLDATA,2,FALSE)"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Paste this code in any module and Run the Macro after activating the Sheet where you want to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about your [`Find()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) is that it returns a **Range Object**. Range objects have the useful [`.Row` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row).

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Cells.Find("NEED DATE FOR PUBLISHING UNKNOWN")
```

You've set the `Rng`, now you can use the row property.

```
rng.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & Rng.Row & ",'VideoIndex.xlsx'!YouTube_ALLDATA,2,FALSE)"
```